# Getting a collection via Ajax to show in view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

All I'm trying to do is have a collection populate in the view when a user clicks a button. But I feel like I'm making this way too complicated and it's not working. See my code - where am I going wrong?

Click handler:

```
 $('#filterrific_results').find('.followup-injury').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();


             $.ajax({
                    url: "/assessments/followups",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {patient_id: patient_id},
                    success: function(data){
                      console.log(data)
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                      console.log(err);
                    }
                 });

         });
```

Controller Action:

```
 def followups
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @assessments = @patient.assessments
    render :followups
  end
```

Followups.js.erb:

```
$('.modal-body').html("<%= render partial: 'followup', :assessments=> @assessments %>").html_safe
```

_followup.html.erb:

```
<%= @assessments.each do |assessment| %>
 <%= assessment.name %>
<% end %>
```

User Clicks Button -> Data is sent to Controller -> Controller renders Javascript -> Javascript renders html partial.

Am I making this too complicated? Also my html isn't even rendering (assessment.name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your partial (currently named: `_followup.html.erb` in your example) should just be the code to produce a single row, Rails will iterate over it for you, and you should name it after the model it represents, ie.

```
 # app/views/assessments/_assessment.html.erb
 <%= assessment.name %>
```

Then in your `app/views/assessments/followups.html.erb` view you'd use that partial like so:

```
<%= render @assessments %>
```

...yes, that's all that's required, Rails will automatically iterate over it, setting the local `assessment` variable inside the partial to each object within `@assessments`.

So, then, the final piece is your `followups.js.erb`, basically you want precisely the same `render` line as you put in your HTML file, but just wrap it in `escape_javascript` so it will be passed properly to the JS `html()` function:

```
$('.modal-body').html("<%= escape_javascript render @assessments %>")
```

That's it.